# How to tag a macro created item to find it later?

Tags: vba, outlook

In MS [outlook](/questions/tagged/outlook), I create some mails or appointments with VBA.

I want to mark them with some kind of tag, to retrieve them later.

I tried it using the [ItemProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864785.aspx) property, but I don't know how to use it by `find` or `restrict` :

```
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set rdvs = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items.Find("[ItemProperties('Tag')] = 'auto-generated'")
```

How I create an appointment (from MS Excel) :

```
Sub createAppointment()

    Dim apptm As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    Set apptm = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    apptm.Subject = "Test"
    apptm.Start = Now
    apptm.Duration = 60

    apptm.ItemProperties.Add "Tag", Outlook.olText
    apptm.ItemProperties.Item("Tag").Value = "auto-generated"

    apptm.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show how you created them?

Comment: `Items.Find("[Subject] = 'Test'")` or `Items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'Test'")`

Comment: Did you try `Set rdvs = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items.Restrict([Tag]='auto-generated')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `Restrict` method to get only the items that you tagged :

```
Set rdvs = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items.Restrict([Tag]='‌​auto-generated')
```

Comment: Something curious: it works when the property name is **Tag** but not when it is **tag**

Comment: @Alsatian : This is most probably case sensitive. Do you create it with `tag` too?

Comment: yes, yes, if I set it as tag and search on tag, nothing found ... It's not a problem, I will use Tag, but it is so ...

Comment: @Alsatian : Awkward indeed... :/

Comment: That's why I didn't found it alone ^^